# how to return back list of data from controller to knockout function to view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, knockout.js

This is my controller where i am returning back list of tags with the post:

```
  public JsonResult GetPosts(int? id)
    {
        var varid = id;
        var ret = (from post in db.Posts.ToList()
                   orderby post.PostedDate descending
                   select new
                   {
                       CityName = post.City.CityName,
                       TagName = post.Tags.ToList()
                    // TagName = post.Tags
                }
      }
```

I dont know, here, is this the way to return back all the tags selected.
**Posts and Tags table are interconnected by many to many relation with a join table TagPost in database which contains TagId and PostId.**

this is the knockout code:

```
function Post(data) {
var self = this;
data = data || {};
self.CityName = data.CityName || "";
self.TagName = data.TagName || "";
 }
 function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.posts = ko.observableArray();
    self.newMessage = ko.observable();
    self.error = ko.observable();
   self.loadPosts = function () {
        // to load existing posts
        $.ajax({
            url: postApiUrl1,
            data: { id: $("#Locations").val() },
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            type: 'Get'
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            var mappedPosts = $.map(data, function (item)
            { return new Post(item); });
            self.posts(mappedPosts);
        })
        .fail(function () {
            error('unable to load posts');
        });
    }
```

This is the view page where i want to data-bind the cityName along with the tags:

```
 <div>
   <img src="~/assests/images/icon.png" alt=""><span><a data-bind="text: CityName"></a></span>
 </div>
 <div>
   <img src="~/assests/images/tag.png" alt=""><span><a data-bind="text: TagName"></a></span>
 </div>
```

Here, i want to return back all the tag name with comma seperated.Please someone suggest me what to do from here.

This is my Post class:

```
public class Post
{
 [Key]
 public int PostId { get; set; }
 public string Message { get; set; }
 public int? cityId { get; set; }
 public IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
 }
```

and this is my tag class:

```
  public class Tag
  {
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public IList<Post> Posts { get; set; }
  }
```

There is a many to many relationship between tag and post class so its creating a new join Table TagPost with column(TagId, PostId).
This is how i am inserting data to this table with on model creating:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>()
                    .HasMany(p => p.Posts)
                    .WithMany(t => t.Tags)
                    .Map(m =>
                            {
                                m.ToTable("TagPost");
                                m.MapLeftKey("TagId");
                                m.MapRightKey("PostId");
                            });
```

Comment: You should really use WebAPI for this.

Comment: @AshleyMedway thnks for the comment, is not it is possible to return back tags by this way. Data is already in database, just i want to show those tags in comma seperated form. dont know how to fetch them properly

Comment: It is possible but you are going to make things harder and more complicated, WebAPI will automatically serialize your object two json on xml based on the request. Basic tutorial here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api about in the code you can see how any IEnumerable of products is returned by the API controller the JSON serialize is done for you.

Comment: Can you post your Post, Tag and other relevant entities? You sure can return that data in the MVC app, don't need an API for that. MVC will also serialize that for you. You query is wrong, but without the classes is difficult to help.

Comment: good. Now, if I get it right, you want to return all the tags of a giving post like this: "c#, .net, stackoverflow".

Comment: yupp exactly @jpgrassi

Comment: I was expecting any solution from u if u can plzz help me out @jpgrassi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should bring the data in the format you want:

```
var data = db.Posts.Include(x => x.Tags)
                   .Include(x => x.City)
                   .Where(x => x.PostId == id)
                   .SingleOrDefault();

var json = new {

    PostId = data.PostId,
    PostMessage = data.Message,
    CityName = data.City.CityName,                
    Tags = string.Join(",", data.Tags.Select(t => t.TagName))                
};

return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This will return the following Json:

```
{
    "PostId": 1,
    "PostMessage": "ABC",
    "CityName": "Chicago",
    "Tags": "C#,.NET,StackOverflow"
}
```

Just note that I've included the City using `Include` in the `Post` but in the model you posted, there's only the cityId. Perhaps you'll need to change that too.

**EDIT**

As per request, to return all posts and related tags change the code to this:

```
var data = db.Posts.Include(x => x.Tags)
                   .Include(x => x.City)
                   .ToList();

if (data.Count == 0)
    return null; //Just return something if no post is found

var json = data.Select(x => new 
{
    PostId = x.PostId,
    PostMessage = x.Message,
    CityName = x.City.CityName, 
    Tags = string.Join(",", x.Tags.Select(t => t.TagName))

}).ToList();
```

Comment: I think it should work but this would return only one post or all the post, i want to return all the post from database. Forget the id parameter and where clause. If i change SingleOrDefault() to .ToList() then it will not work am i right or wrong @jpgrassi

Comment: No. I understood from your question that you'd want to filter by a postId. The code need changes to work in the way you commented.

Comment: Thnk u very much finally made it working with ur help @jpgrassi

Comment: No problem. I edited the question to return all Posts, if you want to check it out ;)